Failed deploy in railway for a monorepo with : wordpress and server at nodes
I have a problem with a deployment. I want to create a monorepo, where I'll set up a landing page with WordPress and a server (for a future dashboard) using Node.js. At the moment, I have two folders: one for the Node.js app and another for WordPress. Each folder contains its own Dockerfile, and I have a docker-compose.yml file in the root of the monorepo. The setup works locally, but the deployment fails.
the folder wordpress it's the same to the file that can download in their official website
docker-wordpress :
FROM wordpress:6.6.1-php8.1-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Instalar extensiones de PostgreSQL
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
    

COPY . .

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Exponer el puerto PORT
EXPOSE PORT

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

docker-compose :
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks: 
      - tropikode-app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - PORT:PORT
    command: ["npx", "nodemon", "index.js"]

  wordpress:
    build: 
      context: wordpress
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - tropikode-app
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - PORT:PORT
    command: ["apache2-foreground"]

networks:
  tropikode-app:
    driver: bridge

Here’s the error message I'm seeing:
 

[Region: us-west1]

==============

Using Nixpacks

==============


context: 31daf3c904b83b14cdf6e79f9497df80

Nixpacks build failed

 

Error: Error reading wordpress/wp-includes/js/tw-sack.js

 

Caused by:

stream did not contain valid UTF-8

 

